# What is the difference between cor and cor.test in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have a data frame that its columns are different samples of an experiment. I wanted to find the correlation between these samples. So the correlation between sample v2 and v3, between sample v2 and v4, ....
This is the data frame:

```
> head(t1)
      V2          V3          V4         V5         V6
1 0.12725011 0.051021886 0.106049328 0.09378767 0.17799444
2 0.86096784 1.263327211 3.073650624 0.75607466 0.92244361
3 0.45791031 0.520207274 1.526476608 0.67499102 0.49817761
4 0.00000000 0.001139721 0.003158557 0.00000000 0.00000000
5 0.13383965 0.098943019 0.099922146 0.13871867 0.09750611
6 0.01016334 0.010187671 0.025410170 0.00000000 0.02369374
> nrow(t1)
[1] 23367
```

if I run the cor function for this data frame to get the correlation between samples(columns) I get NA for all the samples:

```
> cor(t1, method= "spearman")
V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
V2  1 NA NA NA NA
V3 NA  1 NA NA NA
V4 NA NA  1 NA NA
V5 NA NA NA  1 NA
V6 NA NA NA NA  1
```

but if I run this :

```
> cor.test(t1[,1],t1[,2], method="spearman")$estimate
rho 
0.92394
```

it is different. Why is this so? What is the correct way of getting correlation between these samples?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Your data contains `NA` values.

From `?cor`:

> If use is "everything", NAs will propagate conceptually, i.e., a
>   resulting value will be NA whenever one of its contributing
>   observations is NA.

From `?cor.test`

> na.action  a function which indicates what should happen when the data
>   contain NAs. Defaults to getOption("na.action").

On my system:

```
getOption("na.action")
[1] "na.omit"
```

Use `which(!is.finite(t1))` to search for problematic values and `which(is.na(t1))` to search for `NA` values. `cor` returns `NaN` if you have `Inf` values in your data.

Comment: how can I check if my data frame contains NA or not? I think it includes plenty of Inf values as well. Will it also affect? And another question is that I think cor.test is for pairwise correlation, and it needs two parameter for calculating. I think what I should use is cor not cor.test, but I am still not sure if it is the correct function to find the correlation between samples(columns) of a data frame or not.

Comment: @hora See my edit to the answer and read the help pages. You can use `*apply` functions to do pairwise comparisons with `cor.test`.

Comment: Thank @Roland. Now I check my data frame, actually only one row has NA which I think only the values which are related to that row should be NA but not all of them. I also replaced the Inf values but the result is still NA. Actually my question is that why when I use cor.test with the same data set comparing only two samples, the result is not NA. But when I use this "cor" for the whole data frame I get NA. :(

Comment: @hora we can throw guesses at this all day long. Show us the data or reproduce your problem with a simple reproducible example.

Comment: @hora You are not correlating rows, but columns. Please try to understand what I have written and read the help pages carefully.

Comment: Sorry Roland that I am a bit confused. Ofcourse I am calculating for the columns otherwise the row and column names of the answer for "cor" command above would not be the main data frame column names. Actually I run the command with "use"parameter like: cor(q1,method="spearman",use="pairwise.complete.obs") and now the correlations are not NAs. Do you think it is the correct parameter I should use? @Roman Luštrik how should I provide the data? it is a very big matrix with 23367 rows. Is there the possibility to add files here? I can not find it!

Comment: @hora you would generally upload a subset of your data to a third party site and link to it. Or you can make a mock example (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).